# Variable heights for in presented UIView

Tags: swift, uiview, scrollview

0

I have a segmented controller that call two UIViews xibs onto the screen. Each view will vary in length due to their content. As the content for each view is different. The UIView are set in a scroll view.

I am pulling the Selected UIView in front of the others when it is selected using the segmented controller. The problem is that the longer views are still visible when I scroll down. I can't figure out how to only let the scroll go down to the bottom of the UIView that has been pulled to the front.

I was playing around with simpleViewX.isHidden or simpleViewY.isHidden in the tabselected function but that doesn't really solve the situation because I can still scroll down into empty space.

```
class foodinfo: UIViewController {

var counter = Int()

@IBOutlet var tabs: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet var shiftView: UIView!
@IBOutlet var theTitleLable: UILabel!

var simpleViewX: UIView!
var simpleViewY: UIView!

var theTitleArray = ["Title1","Title2","Title3","Title4","Title5","Title6","Title7"]

override func viewDidLoad() {

//Different subViews for each selection
if counter == 0 {
    simpleViewX = SimpleVC0().view
    simpleViewY = SimpleVC1().view
    shiftView.addSubview(simpleViewY)
    shiftView.addSubview(simpleViewX)
}

if counter == 1 {
    simpleViewX = SimpleVC2().view
    simpleViewY = SimpleVC3().view
    shiftView.addSubview(simpleViewY)
    shiftView.addSubview(simpleViewX)
}

if counter == 2 {
    simpleViewX = SimpleVC4().view
    simpleViewY = SimpleVC5().view
    shiftView.addSubview(simpleViewY)
    shiftView.addSubview(simpleViewX)
}

if counter == 3 {
    simpleViewX = SimpleVC6().view
    simpleViewY = SimpleVC7().view
    shiftView.addSubview(simpleViewY)
    shiftView.addSubview(simpleViewX)
}

if counter == 4 {
    simpleViewX = SimpleVC8().view
    simpleViewY = SimpleVC9().view
    shiftView.addSubview(simpleViewY)
    shiftView.addSubview(simpleViewX)
}

if counter == 5 {
    simpleViewX = SimpleVC10().view
    simpleViewY = SimpleVC11().view
    shiftView.addSubview(simpleViewY)
    shiftView.addSubview(simpleViewX)
}

if counter == 6 {
    simpleViewX = SimpleVC12().view
    simpleViewY = SimpleVC13().view
    shiftView.addSubview(simpleViewY)
    shiftView.addSubview(simpleViewX)
}
}


func getTitle() {
theTitleLable.text = theTitleArray[counter]
 }

@IBAction func tabselected(_ sender: Any) {
switch (sender as AnyObject).selectedSegmentIndex {
case 0:
    shiftView.bringSubviewToFront(simpleViewX)
    break
case 1:
    shiftView.bringSubviewToFront(simpleViewY)
    break
   default:
    break
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let selectedView = firstView.isHidden ? secondView : firstView

    if scrollView.contentOffset.y > selectedView.frame.height {

        scrollView.setContentOffset(selectedView.frame.height, animated: false)
    }

}
```

You can also add some padding if you want to